# Angular2 Observable Timer Condition

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have a timer:

```
initiateTimer() {
    if (this.timerSub)
        this.destroyTimer();

    let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000);
    this.timerSub = timer.subscribe(t => {
        this.secondTicks = t
    });
}
```

How would I add the condition to after 60 minutes present a popup to the user? I've tried looking at a couple of questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728827/rxjs-if-with-observable-as-conditional) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557993/how-do-i-stop-observable-timer-or-observable-interval-automatically-after-ce)) but it's not clicking for me. Still new to RxJS patterns...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need RxJS for that. You can use good old `setTimeout`:

```
initiateTimer() {
    if (this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    this.timer = setTimeout(this.showPopup.bind(this), 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

If you really must use RxJS, you could:

```
initiateTimer() {
    if (this.timerSub) {
        this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.timerSub = Rx.Observable.timer(60 * 60 * 1000)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(this.showPopup.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use `observable.timer` and subscribe to it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(){
    var numbers = Observable.timer(10000); // Call after 10 second.. Please set your time
    numbers.subscribe(x =>{
      alert("10 second");
    });
  }
}
```

[Please see more details](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer)

Comment: Also you need to unsubscribe. It is better to place above code in ngOnInit(), and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy()

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this from what I initially had which gives me what I need:

```
initiateTimer() {
    if (this.timerSub)
        this.destroyTimer();

    let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000);
    let hour = 3600;
    this.timerSub = timer.subscribe(t => {
        this.secondTicks = t;
        if (this.secondTicks > hour) {
            alert("Save your work!");
            hour = hour * 2;
        }
    });
}
```

I implemented this before I tried what I marked as answer, so will just leave it here.

Comment: how you do `destroyTimer()`?

Comment: @genuinefafa `if (this.timerSub) this.timerSub.unsubscribe();`