# How to call a component (Modal Popup) from a service?

Tags: angular, service, components

I want to show session timeout popup for every 10 min . I am putting an issued time in session storage in a service file and also from same file I am starting the timer. The reason I am doing this is that in every response I get a new issued time . So I am passing issued time from session storage to a popup. The problem I am getting here is I cannot call a component from that particular service, the reason is "Circular dependency in service -> component -> service -> component"

This is my service file

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})


export class HttpBaseService {

 constructor(public authHttp: HttpClient, private modal: MatDialog, 
private toastr: ToastrManager) { }

public handleAPIResponse(response: any) {

    if (response.accessToken) {
        const tokenInfo = 
this.getDecodedAccessToken(response.accessToken);
        const issuedTime = tokenInfo.exp;
        this.setToken(response.accessToken, issuedTime);
//Here I am starting the timer with latest  issued time.
          this.startTimer(issuedTime); 
    }
    return response.result;
 }
}

startTimer(issuedTime: number) {
///login to calculate time 
//call a modal popup here if time is up. 
this.modal.open(ModalPopupComponent, {

 }

 }
```

This is my ModalPopupComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-popup',
  templateUrl: './modal-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-popup.component.scss'],
})

export class ModalPopupComponent implements OnInit { 

//logic to show countdown of One min to logout automatically

}
```

Need to know how can I call modal component from this service, without any circular dependency. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: why you want call component from service? the normal flow component call services

Comment: I want to show a popup from this service, actually this is for making code generic. This service will check for new issued date from the response token , (here I am getting a new issued date for every singe response.) and if the time is up I have to show a modal popup from this service. Is there any other simple way I can acheive this ?

Comment: you can use Observable timer like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763430/angular2-observable-timer-condition and call open dialog on subscribe

Comment: thats the problem here , I am not able to show a popup here from service .the Warning  Says there is a  circular dependency.

Comment: can you tell me how to pass values  from service to component
eg. In My Service  
private myComponent = Mycopmponent;
const value = 123;
this.mycomponent.someMethod(value)
this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timer in component witch check you variable in service and run Modal like this:

```
setInterval(() => { this.loading = true; this.getSignals(); }, 60000);
```

You can activate this in Component ngOninit
Good luck!

Comment: I have the logic to show timer, exactly as I want , but the problem I am facing is I cannot show a modal popup here, gives me warning , saying , there is a circular dependency

Comment: You must call popup in component by timer, not in service. In component you can check any service variable.

Comment: can you tell me how to pass values  from service to component
eg. In My Service ,
private myComponent = Mycopmponent;
const value = 123;
this.mycomponent.someMethod(value);

Comment: You must import service in component like this: ```import { SelectedService } from '../selected.service';``` then you must declare variable in constructor like this ```constructor(public ch_serv: ChService) {}``` then you can check service variable in component like this: ``ch_serv.var``. May be you create service like component, but service is not component. You can create service by: ```ng g s service_name``` You cannot import components in service.